# Using Core Data for storing files state that are in the NSTemporaryDirectory

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfilemanager

Each iOS application has folders where we can store some of our files that downloaded from the Internet or created directly from app.

So when I download my files to NSTemporaryDirectory I also attach this file to the core data as an entity.

For example I have downloaded file description.pdf and on this point I create entity with full path of this document.

**coreDataEntityFile.path = NSTemporaryDirectory / Root Folder / Folder / description.pdf**

I have skipped `[NSString @"%@"]` never mind about it;

Why I need to store file in Core Data?

I need it for my file manger and core data shows if file is active, is opened or some other state.

What's my problem?

Suppose I have 10000 files here **NSTemporaryDirectory / Root Folder / Folder /** and suppose I want to rename **Folder** to **My Folder**

so the path then will be **NSTemporaryDirectory / Root Folder / My Folder /**

But core data still don't about changes and if I want to change this directory in core data I need to rename all **coreDataEntityFile.path** using new path.

But for 10000 it is not a good solution.

So I just what to rename folder and I think maybe I need to use some non trivial approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using NSURLs and their bookmark feature. From Apple:

> In OS X v10.6 and later, the NSURL class provides a facility for
>   creating and using bookmark objects. A bookmark provides a persistent
>   reference to a file-system resource. When you resolve a bookmark, you
>   obtain a URL to the resource’s current location. A bookmark’s
>   association with a file-system resource (typically a file or folder)
>   usually continues to work if the user moves or renames the resource,
>   or if the user relaunches your app or restarts the system.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

That way changes of the file path will be irrelevant for you, and the bookmark will be up to date all the time. I haven't tried this on iOS for a temporary directory, yet I see no reason why it shouldn't work there as well.